# Custom migration policy to change attribute types not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data-migration

I want to apply a custom migration policy to change attribute types for a given core data entity. In my particular case I have an entity called `Location` with the common attributes `latitude` and `longitude`. In version 1 of my data model both attributes are of type `String`. In version 2 I have changed the type to `Double`.

Next I have created a mapping model including the entity mapping `LocationToLocation`. In the respective value expressions I've added `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "stringToDoubleWithString:" , $source.latitude)`. As custom policy I have added `MyApp.LocationToLocationMigrationPolicy1to2` to the mapping model.

The corresponding custom migration policy file looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class LocationToLocationMigrationPolicy1to2: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
    func stringToDouble(value: String?) -> Double {
        return Double(value ?? "") ?? 0.0
    }
}
```

However, when running my app I am getting the following error message:

> MyApp.sqlite options:{
>       NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
>       NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1; } ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "(null)"
>   [...]
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134190 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={entity=Location, property=altitude, reason=Source and
>   destination attribute types are incompatible}]

I spend already few hours in searching for solutions at stack overflow and on the internet.

Does anybody have some advice for me what's going wrong here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Same issue, did u find any solution for this?